# How to create tabs with linebreaks?

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

I want to create tabs with jQuery and CSS that are capable to contain text with linebreaks.

I tried several jQuery tab plugins including jQuery Ui's tabs, but all of them are messing around the layout, when you insert a line break (e.g. with "br"-tag) into the tab heading.

Now I use the simple and lightweight liteTabs jQuery plugin by Nicola Hibbert, but I think the solution lies in the CSS and will be independent from that.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="example-2">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#1">
            Tab 1 line 1 <br /> 
            line.....2<br />
            line......3
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#2">Tab 2<br />&nbsp; </a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div name="#1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultricies fermentum tempor.
Maecenas rutrum augue vehicula nisi feugiat tempus. Aenean pretium fringilla eleifend.
Ut posuere vestibulum lorem quis iaculis. Nullam luctus ipsum aliquam justo convallis egestas.
</div>
<div name="#2">
Maecenas rutrum augue vehicula nisi feugiat tempus. Aenean pretium fringilla eleifend. Ut posuere vestibulum lorem quis iaculis.
Nullam luctus ipsum aliquam justo convallis egestas. Vivamus mattis nunc molestie nisi tincidunt gravida. Aliquam erat volutpat.
Donec a dolor vitae quam gravida pharetra euismod eget metus. Ut nisi quam, molestie vitae semper non, malesuada quis justo.
Quisque magna velit, eleifend hendrerit vestibulum non, dignissim sed felis.
</div>
<div name="#3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ultricies fermentum tempor.
Maecenas rutrum augue vehicula nisi feugiat tempus. Aenean pretium fringilla eleifend. Ut posuere vestibulum lorem quis iaculis.
Nullam luctus ipsum aliquam justo convallis egestas. Vivamus mattis nunc molestie nisi tincidunt gravida. Aliquam erat volutpat.
Donec a dolor vitae quam gravida pharetra euismod eget metus. Ut nisi quam, molestie vitae semper non, malesuada quis justo.
Quisque magna velit, eleifend hendrerit vestibulum non, dignissim sed felis.
</div>
</div>
```

The example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5TDg9/VkH5R/) at jsfiddle.

Comment: Simply use <br> instead of <br /> is better due to new HTML5 standard. The second version works equally good though. But it is from xhtml.

Comment: thank you for this information. Unfortunately when using <br> instead of <br /> the syntax-highlighting in jsfiddle shows "unclosed" tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to keep the layout from breaking, you need to add a fixed height to your unordered list (UL) element. Then, you can set your List Items (LI) and anchor tags (A) to 100%.

Adding the following CSS rules to your CSS should fix the layout issue. You just need to decide how large your tabs are going to be:

```
ul { height: 56px; }
li { height: 100%; }
a { height: 100%; }
```

Here is a fiddle with the fixed layout: http://jsfiddle.net/VkH5R/15/

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: this solution in fact works almost OK if we can estimate the height of the tabs beforehand, to make it more dynamic, you can just use script to auto-set all the values no matter what you change to the tabs' text as well as font-size ... check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/VkH5R/16/

Comment: I can't think of another way to solve this without using JavaScript to calculate the height, and then manipulate the DOM after the fact. In CSS, in order to stretch a child element to 100% of the height of it's parent, the parent needs to have a defined value for height set.